# Regex help - match specific string but not when wrapped in [!foobar!]

Tags: regex

In PHP we want to replace strings with links but want to give content editors the ability to say don't automatically replace this string (i.e. give them a chance to wrap the string in some specific not characters so it doesn't fall into our logic pattern)

e.g. 
"I went for a walk in the park and came across a foobar"
will fall into our match and be replaced 
However
"I went for a walk in the park and came across a [!foobar!]"
will not.

```
Foobar - should match
[!Foobar!] - shouldn't match
Foobar!] - should match
[!Foobar - should match
Foobar, is cool - should match
```

Having trouble building this regex on http://regexr.com

Comment: Why shouldn't `[!Foobar!]` match and others should? Because of `[!` and `!]`? Are you writing it for JavaScript? What do you need to get in the end? Feel your question is unclear :) ?

Comment: Sorry I've rephrased. :)

Comment: http://regexr.com/3d037 is the closest I can get

Comment: It is for PHP, right? and you do not want to match `foobar` inside `[!....!]`, right? Try [`\[!.*?!](*SKIP)(*F)|foobar`](https://regex101.com/r/rS4jF8/1). If you are replacing, you can also use another approach: match and capture  the `[!...!]` and only match `foobar` and replace with `$1`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS4jF8/2)

Comment: You accepted a wrong answer, [it does not match `*Foobar!]*`](https://regex101.com/r/oC9zZ7/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I understood right*, this should do the trick:

```
(?!\[!)(foobar)(?!!\])
```

See <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ1eK4/3)</kbd>

Comment: This fails to find foobar in `[!not!] this but foobar and not [!this!]`

Comment: @Thomas - it removes the 'a' in 'a foobar'

Comment: [Not sure...](https://regex101.com/r/kQ1eK4/4) The `(?!\[!)` is a *lookahead* and will always return *true* because `foobar` does not start with `[!`. Sorry, the pattern is still incorrect.